# cordova geolocation does not watch or get the current location instantly

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova 6.1.1, and I'm using the latest version of cordova-plugin-geolocation. I tried both `getCurrentPossition(onSuccess,onError)` and `watchPossition(onSuccess, onError)`. And both of them are not updating my geolocation in (lat, lon) instantly.

I will track the position in `getTagLocation()` of my `locator.js`

```
getTagLocation: function(tagId,callback) {
        console.log('in getTagLocation func')
        locator.TrackingLocation();
},
```

and Tracking Location is defined as:

```
TrackingLocation: function() {
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        locator.devicePosition.coords.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        locator.devicePosition.coords.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        locator.devicePosition.timeStamp = position.timestamp;  
    };

    var onError = function(error) {
        console.log("[ERROR]: "+error);
    };

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,onError);
},
```

And in my `app.js`, I will display the position:

```
displayResult: function(data){
        app.display("output message : ");
        app.display(data);
},

connectSuccess: function() {
    console.log("in connectSuccess");
    app.display("Connected to: " + app.macAddress);
    connectButton.innerHTML = "Disconnect";
    locator.getTagLocation('00176883',app.displayResult);
    setTimeout(function() {
        locator.unsubscribeTagLocation(app.displayResult);
    }, 30000);
},
```

From my point of view, what I did is wrapped the original function into my locator. So, in a time period of 30s, it should update my position as soon as possible. But it will not update my position around probably 5 to 6 seconds, sometimes even more than 10 seconds. I didn't find the issue trackers in their repo, so I'm asking my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default setting is **no good**, don't use that.

What I did to change is given the optional parameters:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,onError, {maximumAge: 300, timeout:1000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
```

this change made the output way more instant than default settings.

Since these values are hard coded, it really depends on your hard ware condition. If you want this `watchPosition` work on your devices perfectly, I would suggest you do some machine learning on that.